# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Ralink RT3290, are monitor mode and packet injection supported with rt2800pci that came with the distro?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have a Ralink RT3290 wireless adapter. The distribution comes with `rt2800pci` driver and I've installed no other drivers or patches.

My network interface is - wlan0, and I can put it into monitor mode using:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
```

If I check with `iwconfig`, it shows Monitor mode enabled.

If I try to inject packet with Aireplay, it says:

```
ARP linktype is set to 1(Ethernet) expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211 or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.
Make sure RFMON is enabled; run sudo ifconfig wlan0 up, sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor channel #
```

I can get a list of networks with `sudo iwlist scan`.

My question is, Does this card/driver truly supports Monitor mode and packet injection ? and if yes, how can I enable both Monitor mode and packet injection the right way?

Info - Kernel - `3.11.0-15-generic`, 
Distro - `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS`, no patches, no upgrades, rfkill - `Hard blocked : no`

Upd1 - After I disable networking, then I can go to `Monitor` mode using code above but the moment I enable networking and wireless networking, checking `iwconfig` says mode is `Managed`. **Driver or Card problem ?**

If I stop using distro `rt2800pci` and install `backports` driver, will it work perfectly ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand in this kind of things but I tried exactly the same thing with the same UBUNTU version and the same nic.
try the following:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
```

/**(the internet connection in this stage would probably be gone)

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

to exit the monitor mode:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I read that Ralink rt3070 (with rt2800usb as driver) supports monitor mode, I'll have my AWUSO36NH 2000mw antenna soon, but as you can see, Atheros chipset are the best for packet injection. both driver and chipset support monitor mode, so, follow the instructions under my comment or:

```
ifconfig [interface] down
iwconfig [interface] mode monitor
ifconfig [interface] up
```

To check if it's on monitor mode:

```
iwconfig [interface]
```

For testing Packet Injection:

```
aireplay-ng -9
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too old, but it may help other.
rt28000pci supported chips are
     RT2760, RT2790, RT2860, RT2890, RT3060, RT3062, RT3090, RT3091, RT3092, RT3290, RT3592, RT5360

And for more information you can check
https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Rt2800pci

For packet injection:
aireplay-ng -1 1 -a [The BSSID of the router] mon0
Packet injection can fail due to several reason.You will have to check those one by one as your fully supports packet injection.
:)